# Error Message when using Beautiful Soup for specific site?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i have the following code for loading a website to bs4:

```
import time
import os, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

if __name__ == '__main__':
  srv=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install())  
  driver = webdriver.Firefox (service=srv)    
  waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)         

  link = f"https://www.google.com/maps/search/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.biorochelou.com" 
  # link = f"https://www.google.com/maps/search/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com" 
  print(link)
  driver.get (link)
  try: 
    waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//button)[2]"))).click()         
  except:
    pass
  time.sleep(3)
  soup = BeautifulSoup (driver.page_source, 'html.parser')    
  driver.quit()
```

This works fine for many website eg. for `https://www.google.com/maps/search/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com`

When when i try to run the code for: `https://www.google.com/maps/search/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.biorochelou.com`

I get the following error:

```
$ python test1.py
[WDM] - Downloading: 19.0kB [00:00, 19.5MB/s]
https://www.google.com/maps/search/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.biorochelou.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\DEV\Fiverr\ORDER\robalf\test1.py", line 25, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup (driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
  File "G:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 540, in page_source
    return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)['value']
  File "G:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "G:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: unexpected end of hex escape at line 1 column 870822
```

Why is the BeautifulSoup loading for this page not possible?

Comment: I'm not getting this error when I try, but also I used `webdriver.Chrome` without any `service` argument - maybe its a glitch specific to  `webdriver.Firefox` or your `srv` or even your version of selenium?

Comment: I think the issue is actually with  `page_source` not beautifulsoup...have you considered trying with a different browser?